# Is this a Design Patent or Utility Patent

Tags: design, utility

In reference to the patent: [US20170153408](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20170153408A1/en)

Please let me know what kind of Patent this is,

Design or Utility

& If someone want ed to protect the Look of how a new sunglass's lens looks, would that be a design or utility patent

Thank you

Comment: Asking if a particular patent is a design or utility patent is a duplicate. If the question were limited to the second question about the sunglass lens, I would be in favor of leaving it open.

Answer (score 0):

US20170153408 is an *utility patent application*. Utility patents describe a process/method of production of an article/device. Design patents protect the visual/aesthetic appearance of an article. If you're planning on patenting a novel way of making the sunglasses lens you'd need to file an utility patent. In your case I feel you just need to protect the design of your lens hence a Design Patent should suffice.

Hope this helped!

Comment: You might want to clarify that the linked document is a application and not yet a granted patent.

Comment: how do you know if this patent is design or utility, as no marking is mentioned on the patent?